# Move item from iCloud keychain to normal keychain

Tags: icloud, password, keychain

Is there any way that I can move an iCloud keychain item, in particular an internet account, to a normal keychain? Moving items between keychains usually works with drag and drop, but I cannot drag an item from iCloud keychain to another keychain. I can start dragging, but the items then disappears from my cursor. I am also happy with a command line solution.

I am using OS X 10.11.2 (El Capitan).

Comment: The site works best when there is only one question per question — please limit your question to one main question and ask the others separately if you are unable to find an answer.

Comment: You can right click copy, then change to login keychain & right click paste [I'm not going to try it because I don't want to mess things up]. Presumably you could then delete the original.

Comment: Thank you @Tetsujin, that works! So Apple just forgot to implement drag and drop correctly.

Comment: Glad it worked, let me quickly drop it to an Answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From comments, it appears Apple may have forgotten to include drag & drop - or maybe it's intentional…

Either way - you can right click Copy, then change to the Login keychain & right click Paste.

You can then delete the original.

You will need to re-grant access to Safari by inspecting the item [double click] selecting the access tab & adding Safari to the list of programs.

Comment: Just a note: you have to re-grant access to Safari by inspecting the item (double click), selecting the access tab and adding Safari to the list of programs.

Comment: This is not working for me on Catalina 10.15.5.  I get an error: An error has occurred. Unable to add an item to the current keychain. One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid. -- to clarify: I'm copying from the iCloud keychain and pasting to the login keychain.  It also does not work pasting to a newly created "temp" keychain.

Comment: Yes, this approach doesn't seem to work anymore.